# how to set the color of bar depending on value in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I want to set the background colour for different values of the dataset

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext("2d");
var myObjBar = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: markers[0].templabel,
    datasets: [{

      data: markers[0].batterytemp,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        barThickness: 30
      }]
    }
  }
});
alert("welcome");
var dataset = myObjBar.data.datasets[0];
alert(dataset.data.length);
var maxt = markers[0].maxt;
alert(maxt);
var i;
var color;

for (i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
  alert(dataset.data[i]);

  if (dataset.data[i] < markers[0].mint) {
    alert("inside if")

    /* dataset.backgroundColor[i] = "red";  */
  } else {
    alert("inside elseif")
  }
}

myObjBar.update();
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question here, only told us what you need to achieve. Remember, we're here to help you to debug code, not to write code for you

Comment: Also, please take care when tagging questions; Java != JavaScript.

Comment: i tried its not working so only asked